# Empty output {} for matrix solutions which I know graphically exist

Tags: equation-solving, algebra

I am new to Mathematica, so there's a good chance that I am missing something critical here but I tried to check the documentation and am still stuck.

```
Reduce[{{Power[Cos[Pi/8], 2],0},{0,Power[Sin[Pi/8], 2]}} == {{a/2 + b*Power[c,2],a/2+bcd},{a/2+bcd,b*Power[d,2]}} &&    a + b == 1 && Power[c,2] + Power[d,2] == 1, {a, b, c, d}]
```

When I try to solve this on https://www.wolframalpha.com/, it attempts to Reduce Cos Sin which is not expected. I am expecting the solutions for a,b,c,d. The same in the Mathematica student edition outputs an empty {}.

Have already tried `Solve`, and that doesn't work either.

Please suggest where I could be wrong.
Thanks!

Comment: When you write `bcd`, Mma translates it as a single variable, i.e the `bcd` variable. To have the product of three variables you need `b c d` or `b*c*d`. After fixing this, the commands [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html), [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) and [`FindInstance`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindInstance.html) return `{}`, `False` and `{}` respectively suggesting that Mma does not want to symbolically solve. For [`NSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) we need numerical values.

Comment: Question: could you please provide some evidence for the statement `...for matrix solutions which I know graphically exist`? Could you provide the explicit values that you know satisfy the equations?

Comment: @bmf this is a reduction of a block sphere representation of a state and I know for certain (graphically) that there exists a point (solution) that connects the state to another point on the sphere.

Comment: I understand what your claim was. I was wondering if you could provide said explicit example. Thanks again!

Comment: @bmf Thanks for the tip about `bcd`, it was a rookie mistake :)

Comment: Don't mention it :-)

Comment: Both of the conditions `a + b == 1 && Power[c, 2] + Power[d, 2] == 1 ` can not be satisfied at the same time. `Reduce[{{Power[Cos[Pi/8], 2], 0}, {0, 
     Power[Sin[Pi/8], 2]}} == {{a/2 + b*Power[c, 2], 
     a/2 + b c d}, {a/2 + b c d, b*Power[d, 2]}} && a + b == 1 && 
  Power[c, 2] + Power[d, 2] == 1] ` yields  `False` . But if you cancel one of them, get solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think in fact you have 3 equations for 4 unknowns. What about this?

```
sol = Solve[
  {Cos[\[Pi]/8]^2 == a/2 + b c^2,
   0 == a/2 + b c d,
   Sin[\[Pi]/8]^2 == b d^2
   },
  {a, b, c}
  ]
```

Then e.g.

```
{{Cos[\[Pi]/8]^2, 0}, {0, Sin[\[Pi]/8]^2}} == {{a/2     + b c^2, 
 a/2 + b c d}, {a/2 + b c d, b d^2}} /. sol[[1]] // FullSimplify
```

Comment: you totaly omitted the conditions `a + b == 1 && Power[c, 2] + Power[d, 2] == 1 ` . If you take one of both into account, you get solutions, but all conditons can not be satisfied at the same time, yield `False`.

Comment: OK. There are 3 equations for 4 variables. That generally gives 3 variables as function of another variable - as shown in my post. Sorry, that I overlooked the contraints. (But what about a little thanks that I spent my time to your problem?) . if you add another equation (4 eqa, 4 variables)  you may get an (or more) solutions. With one more equation it is vervy likely that no solution exists, if not by chance. It would be interesting to see your solution.